# Sum of TimeSpans in C#

Tags: c#, linq, timespan

I have a collection of objects that include a TimeSpan variable:

```
MyObject
{ 
    TimeSpan TheDuration { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use LINQ to sum those times.
Of course, (from r in MyCollection select r.TheDuration).Sum(); doesn't work!

I'm thinking of changing the datatype of TheDuration to an int and then summing it and converting the sum to a TimeSpan. That will be messy because each TheDuration in my collection is used in as a timespan somewhere else.

Any suggestion on this summation?

Comment: I used this approach within Linq querry: ... DelaySum = TimeSpan.FromTicks(x.Sum(y => y.DELAY_TS.Value.Ticks)) ... seems working for my purpose. Hope this helps someone out there as well :-).

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't a an overload of `Sum` that accepts an `IEnumerable<TimeSpan>`. Additionally, there's no current way of specifying operator-based generic constraints for type-parameters, so even though `TimeSpan` is "natively" summable, that fact can't be picked up easily by generic code.

One option would be to, as you say, sum up an integral-type equivalent to the timespan instead, and then turn *that* sum into a `TimeSpan` again. The ideal property for this is [**`TimeSpan.Ticks`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.ticks.aspx), which round-trips accurately. But it's not necessary to change the property-type on your class at all; you can just *project*:

```
var totalSpan = new TimeSpan(myCollection.Sum(r => r.TheDuration.Ticks));
```

Alternatively, if you want to stick to the TimeSpan's `+` operator to do the summing, you can use the `Aggregate` operator:

```
var totalSpan = myCollection.Aggregate
                (TimeSpan.Zero, 
                (sumSoFar, nextMyObject) => sumSoFar + nextMyObject.TheDuration);
```

Comment: Just a small correction. It should be `var totalSpan = new TimeSpan(myCollection.Sum(r => r.Ticks)); in case if `myCollection is `List<TimeSpan>()`.

Answer (score 54):

This works well (code based on Ani's answer)

```
public static class StatisticExtensions
{    
    public static TimeSpan Sum<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TimeSpan> selector)
    {
        return source.Select(selector).Aggregate(TimeSpan.Zero, (t1, t2) => t1 + t2);
    }
}
```

Usage :

If Periods is a list of objects with a Duration property

```
TimeSpan total = Periods.Sum(s => s.Duration)
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe this is the cleanest LINQ extension:

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static TimeSpan Sum<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TimeSpan> func)
    {
        return new TimeSpan(source.Sum(item => func(item).Ticks));
    }
}
```

Usage is the same:

```
TimeSpan total = Periods.Sum(s => s.Duration)
```

Comment: brilliant, brilliant brilliant...

Answer (score 2):

This works for both a collection, and a property within a collection;

```
void Main()
{
    var periods = new[] {
        new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0),
        new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0),
        new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0),
    };
    TimeSpan total = periods.Sum();
    TimeSpan total2 = periods.Sum(p => p);

    Debug.WriteLine(total);
    Debug.WriteLine(total2);

    // output: 00:30:00
    // output: 00:30:00
}


public static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static TimeSpan Sum(this IEnumerable<TimeSpan> timeSpanCollection)
    {
        return timeSpanCollection.Sum(s => s);
    }

    public static TimeSpan Sum<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TimeSpan> func)
    {
        return new TimeSpan(source.Sum(item => func(item).Ticks));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I tried and it worked:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<MyObject> collection = new List<MyObject>();
MyObject mb = new MyObject();
mb.TheDuration = new TimeSpan(100000);
collection.Add(mb);
mb.TheDuration = new TimeSpan(100000);
collection.Add(mb);
mb.TheDuration = new TimeSpan(100000);
collection.Add(mb);
var sum = (from r in collection select r.TheDuration.Ticks).Sum();
Console.WriteLine( sum.ToString());
//here we have new timespan that is sum of all time spans
TimeSpan sumedup = new TimeSpan(sum);


public class MyObject
{
    public TimeSpan TheDuration { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: this is the same as @Ani's first solution, just with a query expression instead of dot notation

Comment: @Broken Glass  somewhat.. by the time i posted this answer there was already 2 answers to it.. ;) Guys are real fast here

Answer (score 1):

I put this in a class to add an extension method to a collection of timespans:

```
public static class Extensions:
{
    public static TimeSpan TotalTime(this IEnumerable<TimeSpan> TheCollection)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int TotalSeconds = 0;

        var ArrayDuration = TheCollection.ToArray();

        for (i = 0; i < ArrayDuration.Length; i++)
        {
            TotalSeconds = (int)(ArrayDuration[i].TotalSeconds) + TotalSeconds;
        }

        return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TotalSeconds);
    }
}
```

So now, I can write TotalDuration = (my LINQ query that returns a collection of timespan).TotalTime();

Voila!

Comment: you should have *asked* for an extension method then ;-)

Comment: "I want to use linq to sum those times." - you changed your mind?

Comment: I'm still using linq: I can query my data and then add .TotalTime(); at the end of the query and it works. I'm still learning the framework as you can see.

Comment: @grantnz: it turns out I'm not using TimeSpan anymore.

Comment: per @grantnz you should rewrite this extension to use [Ani's `Aggregate` answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4703056/1037948)

Answer (score 1):

I created extension method for IEnumerable<TimeSpan>

```
public static class TimeSpanExtensions
{
    public static TimeSpan Sum(this IEnumerable<TimeSpan> source)
    {
        return source.Aggregate(TimeSpan.Zero, (subtotal, time) => subtotal.Add(time));
    }
}
```

Thanks to that I can use:

```
 IEnumerable<TimeSpan> times = new List<TimeSpan>();
 TimeSpan totalTime = times.Sum();
```

Comment: For future readers: the answer of grantnz is more robust, as it allows selectors (x => x.TimeSpan)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.Aggregate` rather than `.Sum`, and pass it a timespan-summing function that you write, like this:

```
    TimeSpan AddTimeSpans(TimeSpan a, TimeSpan b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you understand that timespans can't be summed and know to use `Ticks`, it seems to me that this extension to *just* convert a long into a timespan looks more *linq-ee*. I believe it lets the reader have a more readable view of the operation:

```
var times = new[] { new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0), new TimeSpan(0, 20, 0), new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0) };

times.Sum(p => p.Ticks)
     .ToTimeSpan();      // output: 01:00:00
```

Here is the one extension:

```
public static class LongExtensions
{
    public static TimeSpan ToTimeSpan(this long ticks)
        => new TimeSpan(ticks);
}
```