# Sum method extension for IEnumerable<TimeSpan>

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, extension-methods

**EDIT: Sorry for the confusion concerning the names of my variables. TotalHours and Hours are indeed TimeSpans and I'm trying to sum up TimeSpans, not the Hours property of the Timespan.**

I'm currently using this to sum the Hours column(of type TimeSpan) in my table:

```
TotalHours = MainGridTable.Select(x => x.Hours).Aggregate((x,y) => x.Add(y));
```

I've tried making an Sum extension to IEnumerable like this but it doesn't work:

```
public static TimeSpan Sum<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TimeSpan> selector) 
{            
    return source.Aggregate(((t1, t2) => t1.Add(t2));         
}
```

I've searched the .NET source code and found that the existing Sum methods are returned as:

```
return Enumerable.Sum(Enumerable.Select(source, selector));
```

I then tried making my non-generic Sum extension to Enumerable like this, but it is not getting recognized by the above return statement and it just keeps asking for a decimal argument.

```
    public static TimeSpan Sum(this IEnumerable<TimeSpan> source) {
        TimeSpan sum = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
        foreach (TimeSpan v in source) {
            if (v != null) sum.add(v);
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

I'm not that well versed in funcs, extensions and generics. What is my mistake and how can I make this work?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Your current code has several unrelated errors that presumably aren't present in your real code. It makes it very hard to tell what the actual problem is.

Comment: TotalHours = MainGridTable.Sum(x => x.Hours), if you just want to Sum the Values of each TimeSpan in the IEnumerable. Do you want anything beyond the sum of  hours

Comment: @MrinalKamboj I think `Hours` is a property of type `TimeSpan`, and the OP isn't summing the `TimeSpan.Hours` property. Or did I misunderstand your comment?

Comment: @hvd as I can understand, OP wants to add the Hours or TotalHours property for a given TimeSpan, that's what Select and Aggregate would do, which can later on converted to TimeSpan as final result

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Yeah, that's totally not what I think the OP is trying. I think the OP has `class MainGridRow { ... public TimeSpan Hours { get { ... } set { ... } } ... }`. The fact that the OP is selecting from `MainGridTable` strongly implies to me that this is a `DataTable`-like structure with multiple columns, one of which may have a `TimeSpan` type. :)

Comment: @hvd now I am confused, I was till this time taking MainGridTable as IEnumerable<TimeSpan> or else OP has to select the TimeSpan values Column and create an IEnumerable, on which Linq to objects can be applied

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Given such a `MainGridRow` class, `MainGridTable` can be of a type that implements `IEnumerable<MainGridRow>` (just like `DataTable`), in which the question makes sense, and it would explain the problem the OP has: there's no `Enumerable.Sum` overload for `TimeSpan`, which is why the OP's trying to create a custom `Sum` extension method for it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise the confusion of naming the variable Hours and TotalHours would cause. They are all inded TimeSpans and I'm trying to sum them up, not their "Hours" property.

Comment: @hvd though I get the point you have suggested, but I am focussing on fetching an IEnumerable<TimeSpan> from the DataTable or any other structure and do the required processing post it, since now all the Linq extension methods would be available

Comment: @hvd Yes, you got it exactly right, that's what I was trying to do by copying the .NET code for the existant Sum and Enumerable.Sum methods and adapting them to use TimeSpan, but I couldn't make it work. When I tried applying Sum(x=>x.Hours) it was giving me "Cannot implicilty convert TimeSpan to Decimal", which means I wrote the extension wrong and it doesn't recognize it.

Comment: @Rynvar there would not be a direct conversion between TimeSpan and Decimal, you need to use appropriate typecasting for relevant conversion

Comment: @MiranKamboj I know, what I mean by saying it gave me that error is that my extension is not being recognized, thus is trying to use one it already has(decimal in this case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT** Thanks for clarifying what you're trying to achieve. I'm still not sure I really got it, so this will be my last attempt at it :-)

```
    public static TimeSpan Sum<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
         Func<TSource, TimeSpan> selector) 
    {
        var ts = new TimeSpan();
        return source.Aggregate(ts, (current, entry) => current + selector(entry));
    }
```

---

I'm not sure what you try to indicate by `TotalHours`, because obviously, the sum of multiple time spans (that could include hours, minutes, days, seconds, etc. each) expressed as total hours is something else, as just summing up the `Hours` property of some timespans. I decided, that you meant summing up the full instances - you can access the required `TotalHours`, etc. information from the resulting `TimeSpan`.

`TimeSpan` is immutable, just like with `DateTime`, a common gotcha is, that you need to use the result of the `Add` method.

```
public static TimeSpan Sum(this IEnumerable<TimeSpan> source) {
    TimeSpan sum = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
    foreach (TimeSpan v in source) {
        sum = sum.Add(v);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Also note, that `TimeSpan` is a value type (`struct`), thus can never by `null`. So that check against null in your code is superflous.

The LINQ version would look something like this:

```
    public static TimeSpan Sum(this IEnumerable<TimeSpan> source)
    {
        TimeSpan sum = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
        return source.Aggregate(sum, (current, v) => current.Add(v));
    }
```

Again, you need to use the result of `Add` method.

Comment: I added an edit to try and clear up the confusion. I am indeed trying to sum up TimeSpans, not their Hours property. The problem is that I am trying to create a Sum extension that can apply to any IEnumerable and use a lambda to select the TimeSpan property of each enumerated item, thus returning another TimeSpan.


Thanks for the heads up regarding TimeSpans immutability, that would have given me headaches later on.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that works. I also stumbled upon [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13169939/3781436) on a related search, I can't believe I didn't find this earlier. I just couldn't figure out how to use the selector parameter of the function.