# Asp.Net MVC5 TimeSpan addition

Tags: c#, asp.net

I seem to be stuck on adding up my timespan fields. I have read [sum of timespans in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703046/sum-of-timespans-in-c-sharp) but can't get my head around the way I need to use it in my solution. I know that you can't add timespans together without first converting them to Timespan.ticks, how do I do this?

What I currently have is a model with days of the week. I need this so that a user can assign time to a day for a supplier to conduct work against. this is the screen that I would like to sum up http://prntscr.com/alwd1q. This would be for each individual.

My model is

```
 public class Plan
{
    [Key]
    public int PlanId { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [Range(typeof(TimeSpan), "00:00", "12:00")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = @"{0:hh\:mm\:ss}")]
    public TimeSpan? Monday { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public TimeSpan Tuesday { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public TimeSpan Wednesday { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public TimeSpan Thursday { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public TimeSpan Friday { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public TimeSpan Saturday { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public TimeSpan Sunday { get; set; }
```

I have tried to do it the following way but found out that I couldn't

```
   public static TimeSpan Total
    {
        get
        {

            TimeSpan sp1 = TimeSpan.FromTicks(Monday);
            TimeSpan sp2 = TimeSpan.FromTicks(Tuesday);
            TimeSpan sp3 = sp1.Add(sp2);
            return (sp3);
        };
     }`
```

I hope someone can help me please
Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the Timespan.Ticks together:

```
TimeSpan result = new TimeSpan(Monday.Value.Ticks + Tuesday.Ticks);
```

Your Monday property is a nullable TimeSpan so you will need to use the Value. Also make sure the value is populated first otherwise it will throw an exception.