# Cannot implicitly convert time type System.TimeSpan to 'long'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

So I've got the following query :

```
var a = from x in list
        group x by new { x.fname, x.lname } into g
        select new RolesUsersViewModel(g.Key.fname, 
                                       g.Key.lname, 
                                       g.Sum(x => x.FocusEnd - x.FocusStart)
                                      );
```

I got the error, which is on the title of this question in this part : `x => x.FocusEnd - x.FocusStart`

FocusEnd and FocusStart are of type DateTime. Can somebody help? I am new to c# and not sure how to deal with this in an adequate way.

Here is the code for the ViewModel.

```
public class RolesUsersViewModel
    {
        public RolesUsersViewModel(string FirstName, string LastName, TimeSpan totalex)
        {
            fname = FirstName;
            lname = LastName;
            total = totalex;
        }
        public string fname { get; set; }
        public string lname { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan total { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately you can't `Sum` timespans. You could sum their totalmillis and create a new TimeSpan with `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds`

Comment: @TimSchmelter, as I wrote above those are DateTimes, not Timespans.

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703046/sum-of-timespans-in-c-sharp) might be helpful, using the `Aggregate` function and the `+` operator

Comment: @RobertRoss: yes, if you substract two datetime you get a `TimeSpan`, if you substract yesterday from today you get a timespan which equals: `TimeSpan.FromDays(1)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result of a subtraction of two DateTimes is a `TimeSpan`. Unfortunately you can't `Sum` timespans. You could sum their `TotalMilliseconds` and create a new `TimeSpan` with `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds`:

```
....
select new RolesUsersViewModel(
               g.Key.fname, 
               g.Key.lname, 
               TimeSpan.FromMilliSeconds(g.Sum(x => (x.FocusEnd - x.FocusStart).TotalMilliseconds)));
```

Answer (score 3):

This is cause `Timestamp - Timestamp = Timestamp`.
If you want to sum ticks, do

```
Sum(x => (x.FocusEnd - x.FocusStart).Ticks)
```

or for seconds

```
Sum(x => (x.FocusEnd - x.FocusStart).TotalSeconds)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could temporarly add them as seconds or ticks

```
TimeSpan.FromSeconds( g.Sum(x => x.FocusEnd.TotalSeconds - x.FocusStart.TotalSeconds))
```