# Sum of multiple TimeSpan

Tags: c#, .net, timespan

I have to do the sum of more time spans in a DataTable to use the code below, but the total sum is wrong, what is due to this:

**DataTable(dt) values:**

```
    09:21
    08:28
    08:46
    04:23

Total hours: 30,97 //97 minutes is not correct
```

**C# Code:**

```
 TimeSpan totaleOreMarcaTempo = TimeSpan.Zero;
 int conta = 0;     
 foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
 {  
    String OreMarcaTempo = tm.ConteggioOreGiornaliere(dr["Data"].ToString()); //This string contains at each cycle 09:21 08:28 08:46 04:23
    TimeSpan oreMarcatempo = TimeSpan.Parse(OreMarcaTempo.ToString());
    totaleOreMarcaTempo = totaleOreMarcaTempo + oreMarcatempo;
    conta++;
 }
  labelTotaleOreMarcaTempoMod.Text = "" + (int)totaleOreMarcaTempo.TotalHours + ":" + totaleOreMarcaTempo.Minutes.ToString(); //30:58
```

Comment: What would be the correct result you want to achieve?

Comment: exactly what you want as final output?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574881/how-can-i-string-format-a-timespan-object-with-a-custom-format-in-net

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703046/sum-of-timespans-in-c-sharp.

Comment: I would like to make sure that the sum of the total hours is correct @MatějŠtágl

Comment: Could you please state desired result (as a number)? As I am not totally sure what you want to achieve

Comment: It is correct, The format is in decimal (0,97 hours = 58,2 minutes). You have to change the "ToString" part.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

30.97 is the correct number of hours. It *does not* mean "30 hours and 97 **minutes**".

30.97 hours *is* 30 hours and 58 minutes. 58 / 60 is roughly 0.97.

I think you just need to format your string properly. One way to format it is:

```
@"{(int)yourTimeSpan.TotalHours}:{yourTimeSpan.Minutes}"
```

Comment: 58 / 80 is roughly 0.97. should be 58 / 60 is roughly 0.97. :)

Comment: I tried your solution and the minutes are correct but the hours are 06:58

Comment: @TimSchmelter if I use total hours, I return 30.977777777

Answer (score 6):

Value `30.97` is correct (30.97 hours, where 0.97 is hour (60 minutes * 0.97 = 58 minutes),
you just need convert fraction of `TotalHours` to minutes.

```
var raw = "09:21 08:28 08:46 04:23";
var totalTimespan = 
    raw.Split(" ")
       .Select(TimeSpan.Parse)
       .Aggregate(TimeSpan.Zero, (total, span) => total += span);

// Use integer value of TotalHours
var hours = (int)totalTimespan.TotalHours;
// Use actual minutes
var minutes = totalTimespan.Minutes


var output = $"{hours}:{minutes}";

var expected = "30:58";
output.Should().Be(expected); // Pass Ok
```

Comment: Feel free to comment downvote, will be glad to fix it

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the Format. 0,98 hours = 58,2 minutes

```
labelTotaleOreMarcaTempoMod.Text =string.Format ("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", 
           (int)totaleOreMarcaTempo.TotalHours, 
                totaleOreMarcaTempo.Minutes, 
                totaleOreMarcaTempo.Seconds);
```

Answer (score 1):

To print out a TimeSpan "correctly", just use the correct formatting:

```
labelTotaleOreMarcaTempoMod.Text = totaleOreMarcaTempo.ToString("c");
```

or

```
labelTotaleOreMarcaTempoMod.Text = totaleOreMarcaTempo.ToString("hh':'mm");
```

**EDIT** Do note (thanks, Basin) that the second form ignores days.

Reference: [Standard TimeSpan Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-timespan-format-strings) and [Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings)

Comment: This is the correct answer. I don't know why someone has downvoted it.

Comment: @GeorgeHelyar, I am not downvoter, but 1. Format string `"hh:mm"` will throw `FormatException`, should be `"hh\\:mm"`. 2. `totaleOreMarcaTempo.ToString("hh:mm")` will not return total hours("30:58") but return "06:58".

Answer (score 0):

30.97 is the correct value but not HH:mm format.

For me the correct solution is :

```
 var total = Math.Floor( totaleOreMarcaTempo.TotalMinutes / 60).ToString() + ":" + Math.Floor( totaleOreMarcaTempo.TotalMinutes % 60).ToString();
```