# Calculate date and return sum of date format 0:0:0 from list

Tags: c#

[image]

I have one list named IdleList which have multiple dates like shown in the image, a list contains date can be more than 5 and I want the sum of date like 
0:0:11 + 0:0:14 = 0:0:25.

This is my list

```
List<string> IdleList = new List<string>();
string mm = ts.ToString(@"h\:m\:s");
IdleList.Add(mm);
```

ts is TimeSpan and I am added value in the list but I don't know how to get a sum of all time in a list.  And it just a time and not contains a date.

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: `0:0:11` is a time, not date, right?

Comment: you will need to at least add in some dummy date

Comment: Why aren't you adding TimeSpans to a list instead of strings? It would make this task much easier.

Comment: You showed a `List<string>` why don't you use a `List<TimeSpan>` instead?

Comment: [Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.parse?view=netframework-4.8) your string to TimeSpan and do the [math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703046/sum-of-timespans-in-c-sharp)? It would be simple if it was still TimeSpan.. how about a list of TimeSpan?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum of TimeSpans in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703046/sum-of-timespans-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to store the items in a TimeSpan List.

But if you need the values as a string, you can use the following code to convert the string to TimeSpan and calculate the sum:

```
       TimeSpan sum = new TimeSpan();
        for (int i=0;i< IdleList.Count; i++)
        {
            sum += TimeSpan.Parse(IdleList[i]);
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

I strongly suggest you to store a list of `TimeSpan`s instead of a list of `string`s, and just work with `TimeSpan`s all the time. Only convert to strings when you need to output them to the user.

If you have no control of the list of strings, then you can convert it to a bunch of time spans like this:

```
var timeSpans = IdleList.Select(x => TimeSpan.ParseExact(x, "h\\:m\\:s", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

And then calculate their sum...

```
var sum = timeSpans.Aggregate(TimeSpan.Zero, (x, y) => x.Add(y));
```

and print it out:

```
Console.WriteLine(sum.ToString("h\\:m\\:s"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one.

```
 List<string> objList = new List<string>();
        objList.Add("0:0:10");
        objList.Add("0:0:10");
        objList.Add("1:1:10");
        objList.Add("0:3:10");
        TimeSpan CurrTime;
        DateTime CurrDate = new DateTime();
        foreach (var item in objList)
        {
            if (TimeSpan.TryParse(item, out CurrTime))
            {
                CurrDate = CurrDate.Add(CurrTime);
            }
        }
        Console.Write(CurrDate.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert all string items to TimeSpan and Aggregate them. Like this.

```
var timeSpan = new List<string> {"0:0:14", "0:0:2", "0:0:4"}.Select(TimeSpan.Parse).Aggregate((k, v) => k + v);
```

Answer (score -2):

You will firstly need to convert them to DateTime like this:

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.Parse(dateString);
```

Then after you can do something like:

```
long  ticks=myDate.Ticks;
```

then you can add all the ticks and convert back to datetime:

```
DateTime datetime= new DateTime(ticks);
```

Otherwise if you want to keep the strings and add only the last part you would need to do something likes this:

```
var list = new List<string>(){
    "00:00:11",
    "00:00:14"
};

var results = list.Select(x=>int.Parse((x.Split(':')[2]))).Sum(); //Result will be 25 in this case.
```

A Better option of course would be to use Timespan like this:

```
TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:11");
```

And then add all the time spans like this inside a loop.

```
time.Add(Your next time span)
```